# Word to describe friends' location

Tags: wording

What is best to describe a friends' location using words, if I want to show their current place relative to user's? I need to show relative distance and elevation.

Is this appropriate?

> **10 m** away, **5 m** lower

Comment: Can you provide a context for your question? What are you designing for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**m** could mean **miles** or **meters** so be explicit.
**lower** doesn't necessarily mean **elevation** so be explicit there as well.

### Explicitly labeled as two separate values...

> Distance: **10 meters** away
>
> Elevation: **5 meters** descending

### Condensed on a single line...

> **10 meters away** (descending 5 meters)
>
> **12 meters away** (ascending 1 meter)
>
> **3 meters away** (no elevation change)